# OpenCV VideoCapture returns an empty frame only in first call to glutDisplayFunc callback

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, webcam, glut

I have been trying to work with OpenCV and freeglut.

The program involves capturing an image from a WebCam, processing the image with OpenCV, and drawing 3D objects with OpenGL according to the processed image.

It works perfectly fine when I only use OpenCV routines.

The problem arises when the main loop becomes controlled by GLUT. When I try to grab a frame from within a callback I registered with *glutDisplayFunc()* the image returned is empty.

Strangely, however, when I grab a frame from a callback I registered with *glutIdleFunc()* it successfully returns a frame.

And after doodling around I figured out that somehow a frame cannot be captured in the first call of *display()* and works after the second call.

Currently my code is querying a frame inside the *idle()* function.

Regarding such background I have several questions.

1. **Why does this happen?** Is it because the program stalls inside *display()* before VideoCapture gains full access to the webcam? Or is this purely a hardware problem?
2. **Is this safe?** I'm perfectly fine about grabbing a frame from within *idle()*, but is this method safe to use?
3. **If not so, is there a workaround?** If this approach is not safe may somebody please notify me with another way of dealing with this issue?

The program is built on OS X Version 10.9.1 and libraries being use are

- OpenCV 2.4.7.0
- freeglut 2.0.1

Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

cv::VideoCapture capture;
cv::Mat render;

void display()
{
  std::cerr << "Grabbing frame in display()" << std::endl;

  capture >> render; // This does not work on first call

  if(render.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Grabbing empty frame in display()" << std::endl;
  }
}

void idle()
{
  std::cerr << "Grabbing frame in idle()" << std::endl;

  capture >> render; // This always works

  if(render.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Grabbing empty frame in idle()" << std::endl;
  }

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
  int debug_window = glutCreateWindow("Debug");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutIdleFunc(idle);

  capture.open(0);

  if(!capture.isOpened()) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Failed to open camera" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

known problem.

some sloppy webcam drivers return an *empty* 1st frame, warmup or something.

just try to capture 1 frame, *before* you go into the idle loop